# React-intl custom formatters

Tags: react-intl

Is there a way to pass custom formatters for React-intl? I see that the `<IntlProvider>` has a `formats` prop, but looking at the docs for [FormatJS](https://formatjs.io/guides/message-syntax/#custom-formats), it looks like that only allows augmenting existing formatters (e.g. `number`, `date`). My current use case is a list of names, and I want to have it comma separated with the last item joined with a conjunction (e.g. `Steve, Joe, Sandra, Judith and Jerry`). Ideally, I'd just pass in a list (`['Steve', 'Joe', 'Sandra', 'Judith', 'Jerry']`) and the formatter would use the appropriate join form for the language. Is that currently supported?

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain a bit more about what is the relationship between the formatting you're looking for, with i18n? I guess I didn't understand well your idea.

Comment: In English, this might be rendered as `Steve, Joe, Sandra, Judith and Jerry`, whereas in, say, German, this might be rendered as `Steve, Joe, Sandra, Judith und Jerry` (or potentially something slightly different; I don't know German grammar very well). The alternative is to have two placeholders; `allNamesButLast` and `lastName`, which is doable but uglier.

Comment: But in this case, why don’t you simply write it this way in the localized file? React-intl doesn’t do the translation for you. One thing I am sure it handles, similar to what you want is the pluralization, but still, it’s not the same. So why can’t you just have your de_DE.json with the label written already as expected?

Comment: The list of names comes from the code during runtime; it's read from a file and passed to a formatter (it's not a hardcoded list)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could achieve this with the built in **select** formatter as follows:

```
const names = ['Steve', 'Joe', 'Sandra', 'Judith', 'Jerry'];

intl.formatMessage({id: 'layout'}, {
  names: names.map((name, index) => intl.formatMessage(
    {id: 'name'}, {
      name: name,
      position: index === names.length - 1 ?
        'last' : (index === 0 ? 'first' : 'inner')
    }
  )).join('')
});
```

And in your translations JSON file:

```
{
  "layout": "Here are the names: {names}",
  "name": "{position, select, first {} last {\u00a0and } other {, }}{name}"
}
```

This would allow you to change the separator regarding the position (considering certain languages are read from right to left). The `join('')` just concatenates all the "separator aware" names to build the enumeration string.

Note I used the unicode `\u00a0` character for space because the usual space was ignored if placed first in the interpolated string.

Comment: select formatter documentation: https://formatjs.io/docs/core-concepts/icu-syntax#select-format